# Djikstra's algorithm gives wrong result what is going on?

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

According to Djikstra's algorith the least distance between nodes A and D will be 6 which isnt really true since the path ABD has a distance of 4 so what is happening here?

**EDIT**

.Some of you requested(correctly my question was a bit sloppy) how I implemented Djikstra's algorithm.So here it goes:

[image]

Comment: Wrong numbers. Or a bad implementation of the algorithm.

Comment: Please edit your post to show how you got the incorrect result.

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's algorithm considers all paths to a node, rather than taking the first one it finds for each node. When you found a path to D of length 6, why did you stop? You have considered all the successors of the node C, but not of the node B. Considering the path $A\to B\to D$ lets you decrease the tentative distance value of 6 to 4. It is then only because you have considered all possible edges to unvisited nodes that you can cross off D and conclude the shortest path is $A\to B\to D$.

The algorithm in its most general form is indifferent to the order in which these tentative distances are considered, but any implementation will have to use some ordering, such as alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

In dijkstra's algorithm, at the last step you did, you should pick the node $B$ instead of the node $D$. That is because you pick the node with the minimal distance and the distance of $B$ is $3$ which is lower than the distance of $D$ (which is $6$). When you pick $B$, at the next step you will pick $D$ with the distance of $4$ (when its previous node will be $B$), which is the correct answer.